# Styles overriding parent to child components angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a third-party component written in angular, it is rendered as

```
<parent>
    <third-party></third-party>
</parent>
```

The problem is that the styles from the parent and the app global styles are overriding the styles in the child component.

You might ask me to use the view encapsulation but if I do both the parent and the child uses bootstrap this would make bootstrap unavailable for both.

You might ask me to change the names of the classes in the child component but this component is very huge and changing the class names is not practical.

How do I prevent styles from overriding and still use the bootstrap classes?

Comment: Did you tried using something like this in the third-party component: 

@Component({
    ....
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom 
})

Comment: I understand why the style from the global.css overrides the child but the parent shouldn't override it, out of the box angular encapsulate components. can you add class to wrap the child? or maybe share some code?